# XML parse to HTML with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml, parsing

I have some little problem with my scripts. I want to parse xml file with some data elements to my html file. So I try to use jQuery but it doesn't work. Can you help me?

This is my xlm file:

```
<?xml version="2.0"?>
<choices xml:lang="PL">
    <complete>Wskazówka</complete>
    <temperature>300 stopni celcjusza</temperature>
</choices>
```

This is my jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.get('../data/content_data.xml', function(data) {
       var complete = $(data).find('complete').text();
       var temperature = $(data).find('temperature').text();

       $('div.menu_circle').text(complete + "|" + temperature);
    });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

I haven't tried this myself, but maybe it helps:

http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/xml-parsing-with-jquery

Answer (score -1):

The issue is how try to output your variables. Try to append your variables to your element.

```
$(complete + "|" + temperature).appendTo('div.menu_circle');
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @cpburnz okay. Here it goes.

Comment: So... `complete = "Wskazówka"` and `temperature = "300 stopni celcjusza"`, so how does the jQuery selector `$("Wskazówka|300 stopni celcjusza")` mean anything? That's a broken selector.

Comment: @cpburnz the selector is div.menu_circle, the variables are complete and temperature. If you votedown please know how to code, trolling is bad.

Comment: I'm sure I have plenty of experience with jQuery. You have 2 selectors: `$(complete + "|" + temperature) === $("Wskazówka|300 stopni celcjusza") === No selected elements` and `'div.menu_circle'`.

Comment: The issue is not `.appendTo('div.menu_circle')`, that part is correct. The issue is `$(complete + "|" + temperature)` which does not create a text node with the contents of `complete + "|" + temperature`.

Comment: These are variables, not selectors. var complete = $(data).find('complete').text();
var temperature = $(data).find('temperature').text();

Comment: Right, `complete` and `temperature` are variables. But when you call `$(complete + "|" + temperature)`, you are saying: jQuery, find the element(s) identified by the CSS selector `complete + "|" + temperature` which is `"Wskazówka|300 stopni celcjusza"` which, as a CSS selector, does not make sense.